# Input data from email form not going to JSON file

Tags: php, forms, html, json

I have added an email input / form to my Wordpress page and want to collect the information from this as JSON data.

The HTML code is:

```
<form method="get"><p id="myform"><input type="email" name="EMAIL" placeholder="enter email address" required />
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Sign up" /></p></form>
```

The php, which is in my functions.php file, is:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$file = "data.json";
$json_string = json_encode($_POST, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
file_put_contents($file, $json_string, FILE_APPEND);
}
```

I have a data.json file, which is being referenced in the php part of the above code, which sits at the first level of my child theme.

I'm not getting any error messages, and the input field is allowing email addresses to be input, but the data isn't going to my data.JSON file.

I can't seem to work out why?

Any help would be fab.

Emily

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the code. `file_put_contents` function accepts the absolute path for the file. Use the 'get_template_directory()' function for the absolute path. Please check the updated code.

`<form method="get"><p id="myform"><input type="email" name="EMAIL" placeholder="enter email address" required />
<input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Sign up" /></p></form>`

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$file = get_template_directory() . '/data.json';
$json_string = json_encode($_POST, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
file_put_contents($file, $json_string, FILE_APPEND);
}
```

Note: Code is writing all POST data into the json file. If you just want email address then change `json_encode($_POST, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);` into `json_encode($_POST['EMAIL'], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);`

Cheers :)

Comment: Hi Ashikra, thanks for the above, it still doesn't work though :(

Comment: are you using the code under theme functions.php ? and where you put the data.json file I mean url ?

Comment: yes, the php code is in my child theme's functions.php file and the data.json file is in the root of my child theme i.e. childtheme/data.json  It's a shame the site is on localhost, hence me not being able to post a link.

Comment: @Emily Chewy I have updated the code. You missed the name attribute of the submit button and that why if condition not worked. If still not works I need your functions.php file.